# URL alias based on language in PHP

Tags: php, url, seo, alias

I created a multilingual hotel site. The URLs look like the following:

> www.blahblah.com/apartments.php?lang=en

What I want now is for a different language, say German, to have the following URL.:

> www.blahblah.com/somethingElseHere.php?lang=de

I want that, in order to help my SEO for the website.

I think I have to use a URL alias, but I am not sure how to start.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to write a piece of code like this:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "de";
    header("location:index.php?lang=de");
}

if (isset ($_GET["lang"]) && ($_GET["lang"]=="de" || $_GET["lang"]=="en"))
{
    $_SESSION["lang"]=$_GET["lang"]; 
}

function ln () {
    if ($_SESSION["lang"]=="de"){return false;};
    if ($_SESSION["lang"]=="en"){return true;};
}

function lang(){
    return $_SESSION["lang"];
}

function mk_link(){
    $return='';
    $except=func_get_args();
    foreach ($_GET as $key=>$value) if (!in_array($key,$except) && $value!='') $return.='&'.$key.'='.$value;
    return $return;
}
```

And then in your website you will have to use it like this:

```
<?php echo ln()?"Home":"Nach Haus;";?>
```

Nevertheless this is a rough method to do it and you will also have to filter your GET variables in order to make them safe.

However **I strongly recommend a framework** like cake, codeigniter or what else comes handy to you.

Comment: Also as @Michal said you could use mod_rewrite if your URLs have a pretty structured form

Comment: Actuall @mugur what you suggested is not a help for him cause what he needs is to distinqish language versions of the site in the URL... if you limit the presence of the language switch in the URL then it may be contraproductive... at least in my opinion, don't you think?

Comment: I agree but actually he is using GET variables to change the language so he is going to distinguish the languages. Of course mode_rewrite is more elegant :)

Comment: ah, sorry, missed something out in your script... nice idea with having the links renamed accord to the lang... + add mod_rewrite to it, perfect... :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use mod_rewrite in a .htaccess file to make a URL like "www.yourdomain.com/german.html" lead to the appropriate index.php?lang=de.

Something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^german\.html$ /index.php?lang=de
```

There's a lot what you could do with mod_rewrite. Look at some more info here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html.

Comment: I am trying your solution on my localhost, http://localhost/Dropbox/theoxenia/index.php?lang=de but I does not work.. When I refresh, I get the same url. no change! Any ideas?

Comment: the example above is a very short one. it is only suppossed to "invisibly" redirect the user. so when you open whatever/german.html, you get results as you would open whatever/index.php?lang=de, but in the address bar you still see whatever/german.html. however, this is not a complete solution to all your problems of course :) it should work, I use the same code on my server and it works... since I noticed that in your link you use localhost, I would suggest that you verify that your local server supports this methods?